# Show that in the ring $R = \mathbb{Q} [x, y]$ there are ideals that require at least two generators (the ideal $I =\{f\in R: f (0,0) = 0\}$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

**Show that in the ring $R = \mathbb{Q} [x, y]$ there are ideals that require at least two generators (for example, the ideal $I =\{f\in R: f (0,0) = 0\}$)**

What would be the generators for the example I put above? I think it's $\{0,x,y\}$, is this correct?

In what other cases is there more than one generator?

Comment: You don't ever have to include $0$ as a generator... although you can if the set doesn't need to be minimal.

Comment: The ideal $(x^n,x^{n-1}y,\ldots , xy^{n-1},y^n)$ needs $n+1$ generators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write a polynomial $f(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ as
$$
f(x,y)=g_0(x)+g_1(x)y+\dots+g_n(x)y^n
$$
where $g_i(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$. The condition $f(0,0)=0$ is equivalent to $g_0(0)=0$, that is, $g_0(x)=a_1x+\dots+a_mx^m$ (zero constant term).

Therefore, if $f(0,0)=0$, we have
$$
f(x,y)=x(a_1+\dots+a_mx^{m-1})+y(g_1(x)+\dots+g_n(x)y^{n-1}
$$
belongs to the ideal $(x,y)$.

Conversely, if $f(x,y)=xf_1(x,y)+yf_2(x,y)$, then $f(0,0)=0$.

Can $(x,y)$ be generated by a single polynomial?

Suppose it is, so $(x,y)=(p(x,y))$. In particular, $x=p(x,y)q(x,y)$ and $y=p(x,y)r(x,y)$. Can you derive a contradiction?

Comment: Can I come to a contradiction by evaluating side and side? For saying something $0=p(0,y)q(0,y)$ and $0=p(x,0)q(x,0)$?

Comment: @Nash Hint: start with counting the degrees

Comment: what characteristics does the polynomial $p(x,y)$ have? For example, what grade do you have or can you have? I know that the degree of $x$ and $y$ is $1$.

Comment: @Nash Then $\deg p+\deg q=1=\deg p+\deg r$. Surely, $\deg p>0$, or the ideal it generates is the whole ring, so $\deg p=1$ and $\deg q=\deg r=0$. Thus $q$ and $r$ are (nonzero) constant polynomials and you end up with $x=cy$ for some constant $c$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

How about $\mathscr I=(x^2,y)$, for instance, as another example...  or $\mathscr I=(x^n,y^m)$ for $n,m\gt1$ etc...

Answer (score 3):

"In what other case is there more than one generator?" is not really the right question. If $I$ is any non-zero ideal you can give a set of generators with more than one element. For example if $I$ is generated by $x$ then $I$ is also generated by $x$ and $2x$.

You meant to ask when it happens that the ideal is *not* generated by just one element. The answer to that is that happens when it happens.

Btw you still have to show that the ideal in your question is *not* generated by one polynomial...

Answer (score 2):

Yes indeed, $I=(x,y)$. Given a polynomial $f(x,y)$, we have $f(0,0)=0$ iff the constant term of $f$ is $0$ iff every monomial of $f$ contains at least one variable iff $f\in (x,y)$.